# How to get the name of a variable through its value

Tags: python

I would like to be able to generate a dictionary contains the value of the variable and the name of the variable. Therefore I also have to get the name of a variable through the value of the variable.

For example,
there's a list named my_list.

```
my_list = ["foo", "egg"]
```

then there are variables like this.

```
foo = "What the foo"
egg = "My egg is big"
```

Finally, I tried this code:

```
def return_string(name):
    return name

GetNameFromStr = {}
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    GetNameFromStr[exec("return_string(my_list[i])")] = my_list[i]

print(GetNameFromStr)
```

But it is not working for me.

output:
`{'foo': 'foo', 'egg': 'egg'}`.

And this is the dictionary I want:

```
{'What the foo': 'foo', 'My egg is big': 'egg'}
```

Comment: What's `ALL_LEAF_TYPES`?

Comment: You already have such a dictionary - it's the current namespace.  `locals()` or `globals()`, depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

Use `globals()` if variables are global variables like:

```
my_list = ["foo", "egg"]
foo = "What the foo"
egg = "My egg is big"

print({globals()[x]: x for x in my_list})
# {'What the foo': 'foo', 'My egg is big': 'egg'}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
ALL_LEAF_TYPES = ["foo", "egg"]

foo = "What the foo"
egg = "My egg is big"
def return_string(name):
    return name

GetNameFromStr ={}
for i in range(len(ALL_LEAF_TYPES)):
    GetNameFromStr[locals()[ALL_LEAF_TYPES[i]]] = ALL_LEAF_TYPES[i]

print GetNameFromStr
```

`local()` returns a list of all the local variables in scope.

Hope it helps.